# Rails getting started help

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been following the Rails 3 Getting Started guide and there was this note in the guide that I didn't understand:

> In previous versions of Rails, you had to use `<%=h post.name %>` so
>   that any HTML would be escaped before being inserted into the page. In
>   Rails 3.0, this is now the default. To get unescaped HTML, you now use
>   `<%= raw post.name %>`.

I don't really get what it means by escaped HTML vs unescaped HTML. Can someone explain this to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If post.name = `<b>Bob</b>`

then Escaped HTML will show

`<b>Bob</b>`

While Unescaped HTML will show raw output

**Bob**

Answer (score 1):

Escaping HTML just means encoding it so it shows up looking like HTML, so you see `<b>foo</b>` instead of actually being treated as HTML on your page, like **foo**.

The way it does this is by converting special characters into safe versions called HTML entities. For example, the HTML entity for `<` is `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

Html escaping is important for securing rails application over cross site scripting. To better understand cross-site scripting please go through this initial screencast.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/27-cross-site-scripting

For further info about how this is handled in Rails 3

http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3

I would suggest to go thorough this guide about securing Rails Applications which talks about whole lot of things.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/security.html